# Asus Access BIOS Windows 8 Instructions

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi

For [these](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008329/) instructions to access the BIOS from asus, when accessing the advanced startup do I need to be admin?

Comment: Did you try it from a non-admin account? BIOS knows nothing about whether you're an admin user or not.

Comment: No, I haven't. I was thinking that exactly that. I was just wondering. Does Windows 8 only allow admins to access the Advance settings to enable UEFI? The instructions from ASUS don't say, so I doubt it.

Comment: That sounds like a very dumb restriction indeed, but easy enough for you to confirm.

Comment: So based on your comment, I'm guessing no, right?

Comment: @Karan - What do you think?

Comment: I think it would be nice if you checked whether that option is available to a standard user account, then answered your own question. Come on, experiment a little to satisfy your curiosity! It's not like it'll kill your system. :)

Comment: @Karan - HA! I don't mind, it's just that I don't have the machine in front of me. The laptop is at work, and I wanted to use Linux, it was windows normally, but don't like windows.